# TYPO3 9.5 redirect

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

Until 9.5 i used sys_domain for redirecting Domains.

For example: I had a Domain `example.com` and set a redirect to `example.info`.
When a user called `example.com/contact` it redirected to `example.info/contact`.

Now, with TYPO3 9.5, it won't work anymore. When setting up a redirect for this domain (sourcepath: `/`, Respect get: no, REGEX: no) and calls `example.com/contact` it throws an error. 
When change the setting to regex: yes & source path `(.*?)`, it just redircts to `example.info` - contact is forgotten.

Is there a way to get the 'old' functionality back?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to automatically prepend the source path to the destination with the redirects module. Just redirect such domains via .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [or]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.info/$1 [L,R=301]
```